# Maximum stored non-collapsible messages on Google Cloud Messaging Servers

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In the Google Cloud Messaging documentation about Messages with Payload I found the following information:

> GCM will store up to 100 non-collapsible messages. After that, all messages are discarded from GCM, and a new message is created that tells the client how far behind it is.

But I can't find anything whether the 100 non-collapsible messages is the limit for the whole project or  just per device?

best regards,
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the limit if for per device, because the collapse key is also associate with registration ID.

Registration ID is tied to a particular Android application running on a particular device.

Also to note from the documentation:
**However, if you use collapsible messages, remember that GCM only allows a maximum of 4 different collapse keys to be used by the GCM server per device at any given time.** That potentially indicates that the messages are tie to per device.

Comment: Thank you ztan. I think the same. Maybe I need to do some tests on that to be sure.